# VSTS Query - Filtering work items satisfying AND clause for the same criteria

Tags: azure-devops

I Have 3 PBI's.

1st PBI has 1 task with Activity as Development.

2nd PBI has 1 task with Activity as Deployment.

3rd PBI has 2 tasks with Activities as Development & Testing (1 task has the Activity as 'Development' and the other task has the activity as 'Deployment').

**Now i want a query to display only the 3rd PBI which has tasks aligned for activities Development and Deployment only ?**

Any assistance would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Tree of work items** query like below screenshot.

Just specify the 3rd PBI **ID**, and select **Match top-level work items first**:

[image]